# why is value not changing in rowdatabound

Tags: c#, gridview

Why can't i change the value in a specific row in the rowdatabound event of my gridview? the code is entering where the value is set to Test but still shows old value?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="au_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    ondatabinding="GridView1_DataBinding" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="au_id" HeaderText="au_id" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="au_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="au_lname" HeaderText="au_lname" 
            SortExpression="au_lname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="au_fname" HeaderText="au_fname" 
            SortExpression="au_fname" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pubsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname] FROM [authors]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

        var customerName = row.Field<String>("au_lname");
        if (customerName == "Carson")
        {
            customerName = "Test";
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: you're changing the customerName variable value not the data in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot change the underlying DataSource in `RowDataBound`(too late). You need to apply your changes to the `TemplateFields` controls or to the `CellCollection` of the row(in case of `BoundFields` or `AutogenerateColumns=true`):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        var customerName = row.Field<String>("au_lname");
        if (customerName == "Carson")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Test";
        }else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = customerName;
        }
    }
}
```